# How to best tap into this black steel gas line

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

[image: photo of Tee with bushings 1]

I need to add a 3/4” line into this line.  I plan to swap out the 2 bushings and elbow with a tee (and a close nipple) that has one 1/2” for the existing line that goes to a dryer and the accommodate the new 3/4” on the other side. The main pipe is 1.25”.

I am hoping that I can just unwind the bushings without the need to cut and thread.

Will that work and any tips on doing so?

Comment: Unless you have a separating joint in one of those straights... I don’t think you will get that apart. Looks to me as if the adaptor was wound in, then the second and finally the elbow, so without removing the pipe it won’t turn - of course you can cut the pipe but then you need to thread...

Comment: Cut the elbow -- it's the one part you know you won't need any more.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri and where will you put the coupler to allow it all to go together?

Comment: Turns out the was a union farther down the pipe so my job got easy.  Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the elbow at the male threads and then turn it counterclockwise to remove it from the 1/2" pipe. Then turn each of the reducers counterclockwise to remove them from the tee.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that bushings are not allowed to be used within the foundation envelope of the structure, for gas supply pipes. Neither are traditional pipe unions; or "street" elbows (female-to-male like in your picture); or "close" nipples. A "right-left coupling-nipple" assembly is required when tying together existing pipes when you cannot disassemble from one end or another.

You will need to cut something to disassemble those bushings and install the tee, and it might as well be the street elbow. If it were me I would cut out the street elbow then unscrew that 1/2" run at the far end. Then I would install a right-left coupling/nipple assembly at the far end. I would use a "short" (rather than "close") nipple to attach the reducing tee, then I would buy (or cut and thread) 1/2" pipes to reach from the right-left coupling/nipple assembly to the tee.

NOTE- there is always more than one way to skin a cat.

NOTE- the main pipe in your picture appears to be 1", rather than 1 1/4"

Comment: @Junmy - you are correct it is 1” on the main pipe.  That second 1” to 3/4” bushings is proving difficult

Comment: You may need a bigger pipe wrench :) and make sure to back it up with a wrench locked onto that tee, to prevent pipe-strain.